# Passing a parameter to each line in a file

Tags: powershell

I'm trying to pass yesterday's date value as a parameter to a list of filenames that i have placed in files.txt . The filenames come with the timestamp and i need to copy yesterday's files to a network share drive. I have passed $odate as the date in filename in files.txt, i need to replace the $odate with yesterday's date and copy the file from 1 network share drive to another on a daily basis.

i tried passing the parameter($odate) in the filenames for each line and defined as in the code snippet below

```
foreach($line in Get-Content .\Desktop\files.txt){
    $odate = (get-date (get-date).AddDays(-1) -UFormat "%Y%m%d")
    echo $line}
```

PB724_SSNTXN_D110A01_FPRS_$odate*.DAT.gz
PB724_SSNTXN_D110A02_FKEN_$odate*.DAT.gz

I'm getting the list of the filenames as i have put in the files.txt and the $odate is not getting replaced with yesterday's date.

Comment: Can someone please help, me out with the replace script, to replace the $odate in filename with the $odate generated(yesterday's date), i'm new to powershell scripting and this is something that i'm trying as a last resort to complete a task.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it like this:

```
Get-Content -Path .\Desktop\files.txt |
    ForEach-Object {$odate = (Get-Date).AddDays(-1).ToString('yyyyMMdd')}{
        $ExecutionContext.InvokeCommand.ExpandString($_)
    }
```

So, for a file with content:

```
PB724_SSNTXN_D110A01_FPRS_$odate.DAT.gz
PB724_SSNTXN_D110A02_FKEN_$odate.DAT.gz
```

You will get output:

```
PB724_SSNTXN_D110A01_FPRS_20190617.DAT.gz
PB724_SSNTXN_D110A02_FKEN_20190617.DAT.gz
```

Comment: Thank you boxdog for your response, after passing $odate to the file name, the actual file name has time value in its name which i'm using a wildcard '*', so the question i have is for a file name _20190617*.DAT.gz, basing on such a name can i copy the file from source and destination?

Comment: I left the wildcard out as I thought it might have been a mistake in your example, but yes you can copy files using wildcards.  So if your files were named like this: `PB724_SSNTXN_D110A01_FPRS_20190617a.DAT.gz`,  `PB724_SSNTXN_D110A01_FPRS_20190617b.DAT.gz`, etc, then using something like this should work: `Copy-Item -Path '.\PB724_SSNTXN_D110A01_FPRS_20190617*.DAT.gz' -Destination 'C:\data'`

Comment: Can i have the copy statement in the same foreach loop that is passing odate to the file names? Since i need to move all the files that are present in the files.txt from source to destination with odate as yesterday.

Comment: Yes.  You could capture the expanded file name into a variable, then pass it to `Copy-Item` inside the `ForEach-Object` block.